# Tips for fitting garden hose on tight hose fitting/quick connector

Tags: hose, gardening

I recently purchased a 1/2" garden hose and two hose fittings (not native English speaker, this is what the English version of the store's website calls them - image attached) which according to the packaging are for 1/2".

The problem is that the hose is really difficult to connect to the fittings, it's a really tight fit, and I can only get the horse pushed about 5mm over the connector. This is barely enough for the locking mechanism to be able to press against the hose, but when the water is turned on one of the fittings eventually comes lose. I assume I need to push the hose further over the connector.

I've tried to use WD-40 to lubricate the hose and connector, but it didn't really seem to help. I also tried to expand the hose by using pilers, but that didn't really work.

Any ideas?

[Here's an image of the hose fitting from the shop's website](https://productimages.biltema.com/v1/image/imagebyfilename/14-014_xxl_1.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possibly a daft question, but just to be sure - you are unscrewing the "nut" that is on the right side of that picture, sliding that over the hose, pushing the hose under the "fingers", and then doing the nut back up?

If so, and you're sure that that hose and fitting are the same size, then try putting the end of the hose in a bucket of hot water for 15 minutes. It should soften the hose enough to allow you to wiggle it all the way into the connector, and then do the nut up.

Edit: as they say a picture is worth a thousand words. This clearly shows what I'm trying to explain.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HR8OkhLhtYo

Comment: I did indeed unscrew the "nut", no problems there, not my first time doing this but usually hoses fits without having to use much strength at all. I guess this hose is just a bit on the smaller side, even though it's supposedly 1/2". But, good news, boiled some water as you suggested and that did the trick! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem a few times and the fix was to replace the hose. My last problem was with a 5/8" hose and a 5/8" repair end . No matter what I did I could not get any repair end to fit that hose so the rubbish man received it when he collected the trash.